# dependency injection into decorator functions in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, decorator, angular-decorator

When using angularJS you can register a decorating function for a service by using the `$provide.decorator('thatService',decoratorFn)`.

Upon creating the service instance the `$injector` will pass it (the service instance) to the registered decorating function and will use the function's result as the decorated service.

Now suppose that `thatService` uses `thatOtherService` which it has injected into it.

How I can I get a reference to `thatOtherService` so that I will be able to use it in `.myNewMethodForThatService()` that my decoratorFN wants to add to `thatService`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the exact usecase - more info is needed for a definitive answer.
(Unless I've misunderstood the requirements) here are two alternatives:

1) Expose `ThatOtherService` from `ThatService`:

```
.service('ThatService', function ThatServiceService($log, ThatOtherService) {
  this._somethingElseDoer = ThatOtherService;
  this.doSomething = function doSomething() {
    $log.log('[SERVICE-1]: Doing something first...');
    ThatOtherService.doSomethingElse();
  };
})
.config(function configProvide($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('ThatService', function decorateThatService($delegate, $log) {
    // Let's add a new method to `ThatService`
    $delegate.doSomethingNew = function doSomethingNew() {
      $log.log('[SERVICE-1]: Let\'s try something new...');

      // We still need to do something else afterwards, so let's use
      // `ThatService`'s dependency (which is exposed as `_somethingElseDoer`)
      $delegate._somethingElseDoer.doSomethingElse();
    };

    return $delegate;
  });
});
```

2) Inject `ThatOtherService` in the decorator function:

```
.service('ThatService', function ThatServiceService($log, ThatOtherService) {
  this.doSomething = function doSomething() {
    $log.log('[SERVICE-1]: Doing something first...');
    ThatOtherService.doSomethingElse();
  };
})
.config(function configProvide($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('ThatService', function decorateThatService($delegate, $log, ThatOtherService) {
    // Let's add a new method to `ThatService`
    $delegate.doSomethingNew = function doSomethingNew() {
      $log.log('[SERVICE-2]: Let\'s try something new...');

      // We still need to do something else afterwatds, so let's use
      // the injected `ThatOtherService`
      ThatOtherService.doSomethingElse();
    };

    return $delegate;
  });
});
```

---

You can see both approaches in action in this [demo](https://codepen.io/ExpertSystem/pen/wMavpY?editors=001).

Comment: I was under the impression that the second alternative is not possible because services are not yet available during the config phase.

Comment: They are not. But the decorator in not run in the config phase (it is just registered). It is actually run in the "run" phase, so services are available for injection as usual.

Comment: Thanks, for the clarification.